# Add tags `<td>` (new cells) and text to a table in html with python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, replace, tags

I have an html file created with python (df.to_html) that contains several tables and I want to add an empty line to a table and change the color of that line to separate two parts of the table.
The part to be modified is:

```
<tr>
<td>II</td>
<td>LARGE (XL)</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
```

adding new tags to the table without any data, and changing the style, I want to turn it into:

```
<tr style="text-shadow; color: #fff; background-color: #E8E446;">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<td>II</td>
<td>LARGE (XL)</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
```

First, I must locate the part of the table that interests me, which includes: `<tr> <td>II</td> <td>LARGE (XL)</td>` and then add the new part in front.
As there are several lines I cannot use `replace` and with `Beautifulsoup` I locate the value 'II' of `<td>II</td>`, but I do not know how to follow.

Greetings and thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this - Check out the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag) for `new_tag()` or `insert_before()`

```
soup.tr['style'] = 'text-shadow; color: #fff; background-color: #E8E446;'
for i in range(4):
    soup.tr.td.insert_before(soup.new_tag('td'))
```

##### Example

Feel free to adapt for your needs and try to `print(soup.prettify())` if necessary:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<tr>
<td>II</td>
<td>LARGE (XL)</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.tr['style'] = 'text-shadow; color: #fff; background-color: #E8E446;'
for i in range(4):
    soup.tr.td.insert_before(soup.new_tag('td'))

soup
```

##### Output

```
<tr style="text-shadow; color: #fff; background-color: #E8E446;">
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>II</td>
<td>LARGE (XL)</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
```